# Generic Dictionary with a value as a Interface with a Generic reference

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I want to have a Dictionary where the values are generic objects and will not be the same for each value int he dictionary.  How can this be done, I feel like I am missing something simple.

EG

```
    public interface IMyMainInterface
    {
        Dictionary<string, IMyInterface<T>> Parameters { get; }
    }

    public interface IMyInterface<T>
    {
        T Value
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        void SomeFunction();
    }

Result:
dic.Add("key1", new MyVal<string>());
dic.Add("key2", new MyVal<int>());
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't do that because `T` has no meaning in `IMyMainInterface`. If your aim is for each value to be an implementation of *some* `IMyInterface<T>` but each value could be an implementation for a different `T`, then you should probably declare a base interface:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    void SomeFunction();
}

public interface IMyInterface<T> : IMyInterface
{
    T Value { get; set; }
}
```

then:

```
public interface IMyMainInterface
{
    Dictionary<string, IMyInterface> Parameters { get; }
}
```

EDIT: Given your updated question, it looks like this is what you're trying to do. If you want to know *why* you have to do this, think about how you would try to *use* the values in the dictionary if you were able to use your original code. Imagine:

```
var pair = dictionary.First();
var value = pair.Value;
```

What would type could `value` be inferred as?

---

If, however, each value should be of the *same* `T`, then you just need to make your other interface generic too. To make it clearer, I've renamed the type parameter to keep the Ts separate:

```
public interface IMyMainInterface<TFoo>
{
    Dictionary<string, IMyInterface<TFoo>> Parameters { get; }
}
```

Comment: If I take this route, to pull the value out from the dictionary I would have to cast it to the type. ie MyDict["key"].Value.Value (Yes bad terminology)

Comment: @Sytone: Yes. That's absolutely necessary anyway - because otherwise you could try to pull out the value for "key2" as a string instead of an int... how could the compiler possibly know what you wanted?