# Parameterize a generic interface - Create a Dictionary<Type, Interface<T>>?

Tags: c#, generics, interface, strategy-pattern

Sorry the title is confusing, I don't know if I said it right, not sure what this thing is called... Feel free to edit it after you read the question if you want.

I'm refactoring my old code when I noticed there are a lot of places where I could use the Strategy pattern. I have an inventory system, and items - There are more than one ways to add an item - Normal way, forceful way, etc. You could also swap items, again, with more than one way - So I figured those are good places to use that pattern.

Here is what I have, for adding items:

```
public interface IAddingStrategy<T> where T : AddArgs
{
    bool Add(T args);
}

public class NormalAdd : IAddingStrategy<NormalAddArgs>
{
    public bool Add(NormalAddArgs args)
    {
        // normal adding logic...
    }
}

public class ForceAdd : IAddingStrategy<ForceAddArgs>
{
    public bool Add(ForceAddArgs args)
    {
        // force adding logic...
    }
}

// other strategies...

public abstract class AddArgs
{
}

public class NormalAddArgs : AddArgs
{
    public readonly param1 p1;
    public readonly param2 p2;
    etc;

    public NormalAddArgs(param1 p1, param2 p2, etc)
    {
        this.p1 = p1;
        this.p2 = p2;
        this.etc = etc;
    }
}

public class ForceAddArgs : AddArgs
{
    public param3 p3;

    public ForceAddArgs(param3 p3)
    {
        this.p3 = p3;
    }
}

// other adding args...
```

Now what I'm trying to do - But don't know how to, is:

```
public class Adder
{
    private Dictionary<Type, SOMETHING> dic = new Dictionary<Type, SOMETHING>();
    public Adder()
    {
        dic.Add(typeof(NormalAdd), new NormalAdd());
        dic.Add(typeof(ForceAdd), new ForceAdd());
        dic.Add(typeof(EtcAdd), new EtcAdd());
    }
}
```

What should `SOMETHING` be? I want it to be any adding strategy - But if I go for `IAddingStrategy` - it doesn't work since it requires me to specify the `<T>` parameter which if I do, the dictionary can't hold all the possible types of strategies... ;(

Any ideas how to go about this? what should `SOMETHING` be?
Am I right of using the strategy pattern in this situation? If not, what's the best approach to this?

Thanks all for your help.

EDIT: One way around this, would be something like this:

```
public interface IAddingStrategy
{
    void Add(AddArgs args);
}

public class NormalAdd: IAddingStrategy
{
    public void Add(AddArgs args)
    {
        if (args is NormalAddArgs)
            // normal add logic
    }
}

public class ForceAdd: IAddingStrategy
{
    public void Add(AddArgs args)
    {
        if (args is ForceAddArgs)
            // force add logic
    }
}
```

Then the dictionary would simply be `<Type, IAddingStrategy>`

But really, I don't like the `if` thing, it just doesn't feel right - what if someone passes the wrong type of arg? that is something only detected at run-time, I want to detect the thing at compile-time. - Using generics I was able to achieve that.

Comment: One thing you need to ask yourself is: "How far do I want the generics to proliferate through my code?" Your problem focuses on adding the items to a particular type of dictionary, but you also have to retrieve those items and work with a return type. And the caller of that method will need to know the specific types, and so on.

Comment: You could also make `IAddingStrategy<T>` inherit from `IAddingStrategy`. That way, each type is forced to implement a strongly-typed method(s) and its weakly-typed counterpart. The weakly-typed method then casts and calls the strongly-typed equivalent. You end up with a lot of casts and it's not completely type safe, but you get to work with a non-generic interface when needed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes I already tired doing that. But I didn't really know what to put inside `IAddingStrategy` apart from being empty. Making my dictionary now `<Type, IAddingStrategy>` means that I have to cast the value back - which is something I don't quite prefer.

Sorry abut I don't get what you mean with "weakly-typed" and "strongly-typed"

Comment: I'm using the terms "strong" and "weak" typing loosely with regards to the types implemented by an interface (not compile-time checking). For your scenario, "strongly-typed" = you are working with a derived type that is specific enough for your needs, whereas "weakly-typed" you are working with a type as a less-derived type.

Answer (score 1):

Per my comments: it may make sense to minimize the exposure of the generic interface, rather than requiring generic arguments to the chain of callers. One way to do this is to implement both a generic and non-generic interface.

PROS:

- You can now work with a non-generic interface.
- Reasonable type safety (in most cases).

CONS:

- Casts are required.
- Every method needs two implementations.
- Type safety isn't guaranteed by the compiler.

```
/// <summary>Some common base type.</summary>
public interface IAddArgs {}

/// <summary>Non-generic interface.</summary>
public interface IAddingStrategy
{
    void Add( IAddArgs obj );
}

/// <summary>Generic version.</summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
public interface IAddingStrategy<T> : IAddingStrategy
    where T : IAddArgs
{
    void Add( T obj );
}

public class NormalAddArgs : IAddArgs {}

public class NormalAdd : IAddingStrategy<NormalAddArgs>
{
    public void Add( NormalAddArgs obj )
    {

    }

    public void Add( IAddArgs obj )
    {
        Add( (NormalAddArgs)obj );
    }
}
```

This does leave the nagging problem of how to create the correct type of arguments in the first place, i.e. what class has enough information to create an instance of `NormalAddArgs` so that it can be passed to the appropriate strategy?

One way is to ask each type to create these types for you:

```
/// <summary>Non-generic interface.</summary>
public interface IAddingStrategy
{
    void Add( IAddArgs obj );

    // "context" can be a type that provides additional info
    IAddArgs CreateAddArgs( object context );
}

public class NormalAdd : IAddingStrategy<NormalAddArgs>
{
    public void Add( NormalAddArgs obj ) { }

    public void Add( IAddArgs obj )
    {
        Add( (NormalAddArgs)obj );
    }

    public IAddArgs CreateAddArgs( object context )
    {
        return new NormalAddArgs();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I appreciate your effort. But if I wanna go casting, I would go with the work-around I posted in my edit section as it avoids dealing with generics all together, but has the downside of not detecting the type at compile time. But it's certainly less 'casty' than your suggestions.

The reason I mentioned "Parameterize a generic interface" is because, if you look at `<Type, Interface<T>>` - Can't we like, extract this `Interface<T>` to another generic type `G`? I was hoping there was some acrobatics to be done with generics, to get the type of behavior I want.

Comment: [You can read up on covariant/contravariant interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd997386.aspx) (if you haven't already done so), although I'm not sure there's a way to make your particular example work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are going to be able to have a `Dictionary<Type, Interface<T>>` in your case since you would need to define T to be common to all values in the dictionary.

Jon Skeet gives an excellent answer to a similar question: [Generic Dictionary with a value as a Interface with a Generic reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4070637/39532). I hope it helps you too.