# Why do I have to specify a generic type arg, when it's pretty obvious what the type is, from the input args?

Tags: c#, generics, arguments, generic-type-argument

So, after I gave up hope on finding the optimal solution that I was looking for in my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20084917/parameterize-a-generic-interface-create-a-dictionarytype-interfacet), I now fall back to implementing my strategy in the way I described in my first edit. It's not that bad, but there's something I'm not convinced about...

(You don't have to read what's in that link to answer this question, but I just added it if someone wanted more details about what I'm doing)

Here is what I have now, for adding items:

```
public interface IAddingStrategy
{
    bool Add(AddArgs args);
}

public class NormalAdd : IAddingStrategy
{
    public bool Add(AddArgs args)
    {
        if (!(args is NormalAddArgs))
            throw new Exception("NormalAdd: Invalid args!");
        Console.WriteLine("Normal add");
        return true;
    }
}

public class ForceAdd : IAddingStrategy
{
    public bool Add(AddArgs args)
    {
        if (!(args is ForceAddArgs))
            throw new Exception("NormalAdd: Invalid args!");
        Console.WriteLine("Force add");
        return true;
    }
}

public abstract class AddArgs
{
}

public class NormalAddArgs : AddArgs
{
    public int row;
    public int col;

    public NormalAddArgs(int row, int col)
    {
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
    }
}

public class ForceAddArgs : AddArgs
{
    public int id;

    public ForceAddArgs(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

public class Adder
{
    private Dictionary<Type, IAddingStrategy> dic = new Dictionary<Type, IAddingStrategy>();
    public Adder()
    {
        dic.Add(typeof(NormalAdd), new NormalAdd());
        dic.Add(typeof(ForceAdd), new ForceAdd());
    }

    private IAddingStrategy GetStrategy(Type type)
    {
        IAddingStrategy strategy;
        if (!dic.TryGetValue(type, out strategy))
            return null;
        return strategy;
    }

    public bool Add<T, V>(V args) where T : IAddingStrategy where V : AddArgs
    {
        IAddingStrategy strategy = GetStrategy(typeof(T));
        if (strategy == null)
            return false;
        return strategy.Add(args);
    }
}
```

It's that last bit that is annoying me. If I wanna use this adder now, I must do:

```
var adder = new Adder();
adder.Add<NormalAdd, NormalAddArgs>(new NormalAddArgs(10, 5));
```

Why do I have to specify the 2nd generic arg if it's very clear from the argument, that I'm using a `NormalAddArgs`? i.e. why can't I just do `adder.Add<NormalAdd>(new NormalAddArgs(10, 5))`? As this is what I was ultimately hoping to do...

So, why can't I do this? Is there some constraint I must add to do this, or...?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Because type inference is an all or nothing affair. It either has to infer *all* of the types for the call, or none of them. And you're having to tell it `NormalAdd`.

Comment: BTW to judge from your code, there is no need to have the `V` type argument at all! You aren't getting anything out of making the type of `args` generic. Just make it `AddArgs args`.

Comment: Thanks for your input guys. Yes Anton, you are right. I thought I was putting some type-safe constraints, but it seems that I wasn't. My guess is that `Add<T, V>(V args) where T : IAddingStrategy<V> where V : AddArgs` is what I meant. But since implementing the `IAddingStrategy` in a generic way gave me trouble that I couldn't deal with (see my link ^) - Not sure if it's my ignorance or lack of language freedom, I guess there's no way... Thanks again.